# Apache file permission

Tags: linux, apache, command-line-interface

I want to add a group (for example 'muppets') as well as have apache as the owner of a folder; however the following command does not seem to add the group to the permission. Am I adding it incorrectly?

```
chown -R apache:muppets html/wp-content
```

or

```
chown -R apache.muppets html/wp-content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the group ownership of a file or directory with the command:

```
chgrp group_name file/directory_name
```

You must be a member of the group to which you are changing ownership to.

not an expert so please check the following resources :

http://www.mcsr.olemiss.edu/unixhelp/tasks/change_own.html

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html